# jQuery bind event on element fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

We are using jQuery 2.1.4 and have written out own JavaScript class that should take care of the event. It is a very simple "application". All it does is taking care of submitting a form. Before that, it processes the data.

Our initial method that we call on rendering the page:

```
OWebForm.prototype.init = function(){
    console.log("init Method called");

    ...
    $("#submit_message").on("click", this._submit);
    console.log($("#submit_message"));
    ...
}
OWebForm.prototype._submit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("_submit Method called");
...
    }
```

Once the button "`#submit_message`" is clicked, it is supposed to call the `_submit` method of the `OWebForm` class. When looking at the element within the console I can see that it is not bound to anything, when the page is loaded. Hence the code is not executed once the button is clicked.

In the HTML I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
        var _oWebForm = new OWebForm("0bcfwqx23xv02dfaqfujdqyafziic4b07uxkkg1y6lkof7x0px0vjm2tpaik2l2rmlrhnjya0bvctnpq26dqcom1ij5zpibodke3rs1z4f2syllthtj0kpl3p4vrw0vw");       
        _oWebForm.init();
    </script>
```

From the documentation I understood, that the function has to exist before it is bound to an element event. Is this not the case when working with objects? How would I fix this?

Comment: How you are using `OWebForm.prototype.init`?

Comment: @Satpal I have adjusted the question and included the piece of code, that I use in the HTML to build and call the OWebForm Class

Comment: Have you tried document-ready handler? `$(function(){ //Your code });`

Comment: @Satpal, well apparently that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is executed before the DOM is loaded so the element doesn't exist yet, and the jQuery selector doesn't match anything, so no elements get a click handler bound to them. You need to call the `init()` method with in [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _oWebForm = new OWebForm("0bcfwqx23xv02dfaqfujdqyafziic4b07uxkkg1y6lkof7x0px0vjm2tpaik2l2rmlrhnjya0bvctnpq26dqcom1ij5zpibodke3rs1z4f2syllthtj0kpl3p4vrw0vw");
    _oWebForm.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
var OWebForm = function(a){

};
OWebForm.prototype.init = function() {
  alert("init Method called");

  $("#submit_message").on("click", this._submit);
}
OWebForm.prototype._submit = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("_submit Method called");
}
$(function() {
  var _oWebForm = new OWebForm("0bcfwqx23xv02dfaqfujdqyafziic4b07uxkkg1y6lkof7x0px0vjm2tpaik2l2rmlrhnjya0bvctnpq26dqcom1ij5zpibodke3rs1z4f2syllthtj0kpl3p4vrw0vw");
  _oWebForm.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<form id="myFrm">
    <input type="text">
    <input id="submit_message" type="submit" value="Click me To test">
</form>
```

You need to substitute:

```
$("#submit_message").on("click", this._submit);
```

with:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_message", this._submit);
```

If the submit_message is not already loaded!